# Obtaining extents of each data-driven page using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, extents, data-driven-pages

I have a set of index polygons (rectangles) that vary in size and orientation on which data-driven pages are based. I am looking for a method that would give me extents Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, & Ymax for each page.

Is there a built-in way to do this, perhaps with the ArcPy mapping module or can I look at the centroid of each index polygon, do some math based on page size, and then have the desired extents?

EDIT:
I was playing around with this and I think I've started to locate a solution. Using the dataframe's extent property I am able to get the information I need. Now, all I have to do is iterate over the data driven pages and get the extent of each.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(Map_Path)
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
for page in pages:
  print DF.extent
```

Comment: See examples of looping through pages at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/datadrivenpages-class.htm